# Why does Ubuntu 14.04.2 have the bind9-host packages upon installation?

Tags: bind, ubuntu-14.04

Why does Ubuntu 14.04.2 have the `bind9-host` packages upon installation? Is this a bundled upon installing the Ubuntu OS? Is there a way to avoid having this packages upon installation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason the package is called `bind9-host` is because it's part of the bind9 suite. However, [it doesn't include the entire bind server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/bind9-host/filelist), just the `host` executable (and documentation). `host` [is a simple utility for performing DNS lookups](http://linux.die.net/man/1/host), not a DNS server.

You probably shouldn't remove it, since there are probably several scripts that depend on it.